# What should lowest supported resolution be for website?

Tags: screen-resolution

I'm developing a web site, but I don't know what the lowest 'supported' resolution should be.  I know that it will function in all resolutions, but by 'supported' I mean that all the content will fit in the page without scrolling from side to side.  Should I even think about 'supporting' 1024x768?

Comment: What about phones with tiny screens? Do you want to support those?

Comment: Not at the moment because I plan on making a mobile site later.

Answer (score 6):

There isn't a correct answer here, other than "know your audience". That's not a very easy thing to do early on in development, unless you are targeting a very specific niche audience.

The common approach for a generic website would be to check current browser display statistics for popular sites:

1. [W3 Counter](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php)
2. [W3Schools Browser Display Statistics](http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_display.asp)

1024x768 is still a very popular resolution, and a safe bet. And, although I haven't found any official stats, it's obviously the resolution Stack Exchange targets.

Comment: Please check out and refer to [w3fools](http://w3fools.com/) if you link to parts of w3schools.

Comment: @JonasWielicki While I am well aware of the tons of inaccurate information w3schools hosts, I really don't think w3fools is relevant here: I'm linking to their browser display stats, not to their content. It's perfectly fine to help raise awareness on the inaccuracy of w3schools, but don't overdo it, please.

Answer (score 1):

> Not at the moment because I plan on making a mobile site later.

I'll focus on the desktop side of things in this answer.

According to [Net Applications](http://netmarketshare.com/report.aspx?qprid=17&qpob=UV+DESC), 1024x768 is the most popular resolution used today with over 15%. The next step down in 'desktop' sizes is 800x600, but it only has a share of 0.89%, so you probably won't have to bother supporting resolutions below 1024x768 on your desktop site.

Answer (score 1):

A safe width for content on desktop browsers is 960px, which leaves just enough room for a simple background on the very common 1024x768 displays mentioned in other answers. A 960px width is also friendly to [grid layouts](http://fernvale.wordpress.com/2008/10/07/optimal-html-width-960-pixels/).

In case you want to go the more flexible route and support not worry too much about certain ranges of resolutions (mobile devices probably nonwithstanding), consider [liquid layouts](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/).

Answer (score 1):

I 100% agree with @Yannis this, its a target audience question. 1024 wide is a good baseline for a worldwide audience, but if you're website isn't for the 'average' internet user you may have a really good reason to use a wider (or narrower layout). For example if you are targeting power users 1280 or even 1600 may be acceptable.

Another possiblity would be to use a variable layout which many modern sites use. This means adjusting your width (or even your whole css) based on the current users browser width. This gives a really sleek feel to your sites.

One really good example of the usage of a variable layout is inside the Trello application.

Comment: I'm usually at a 1920x1080 display (or two or three), but on every site I've ever build 1024 is the most popular resolution (at least it was last time I checked), regardless of the audience. But if you really know your audience before hand, any target resolution would be acceptable if it fits their needs. 1280/1600 would be great for powerusers, agreed.

Comment: @YannisRizos yeah most of us techies live above 1600, the massive variation in screen widths is a big driver for non-fixed width websites, If you are like us, it makes a lot more sense to view a page using a wider layout if possible. In addition most new consumer monitors are using a 16x9 aspect ratio with 1920x for 1080p playback. this means that using a 1024 layout a significant amount of people will only be using 50% of their available real estate

Answer (score 0):

1024x768 should be ok. But find out what resolution the person signing the check uses and try to develop a liquid layout to avoid side scrolling.